# How to delete selected table data from Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to remove selected info from a mysql table but cant see to get it correct, here is my code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$username = addslashes($_GET['username']);
$password = addslashes($_GET['password']);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM users (username, password) VALUES ('$username', '$password')");
?>
```

The database connection is setup in the "config.php" I know that works.

I know it is in no way secure I just need it to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit - I should probably say that I am trying to delete through the url.

Comment: read [DELETE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-delete-query.htm) SQL Syntax

Comment: Come on... this is basic stuff. Please find the time to go through some SQL tutorial... there are many out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query to delete rows should be

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password = '$password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is invalid, instead consider:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$username = addslashes($_GET['username']);
$password = addslashes($_GET['password']);

mysql_query("DELETE FROM users where username='$username' and password='$password'");
?>
```

Comment: mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. Recommend OP to use this